# Is there anything redundant about the collocation "discuss together"?

Tags: collocation, phrasing

I'm not comfortable with "discuss together" but I see it used quite a bit especially in translations. I think it's clunky usage as "together" is embedded in the meaning of "discuss".

Is "discuss together" redundant, or just bad style, or actually trending as acceptable.

Comment: Not a question.  Not even asking for opinions.  Just expressing his own opinion.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask, is "discuss together" redundant, or just bad style, or actually trending as acceptable.

Comment: well "discuss together" sounds akward.. but "lets discuss this together" is less so ... ... perhaps redundant on the surface but probably used as a short , less formal way of saying "Let's get together and discuss this."  Certainly that longer form means... let's move this dialague from writing or phone and discuss this when we are in the same place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a peeve

Comment: Consider that "We need to discuss this" may imply a group meeting, or may simply imply that the people involved should go back to their offices and have some one-on-one discussions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, can't something be both a peeve and a legit question?  Or are you referring to phrasing a question as a question rather than as a complaint?

Comment: I think the OP as a legitimate misunderstanding that this forum is meant for helping with. The comments should have been helpful to him so far.. in my opinion at least

Comment: Yes, most helpful. Sorry, I've been away. Please advise how to "close the question" as I'm new to this blog

Comment: I meant to seek general opinion on a specific usage issue and have so far gotten plenty. Thank you.

Comment: I add *together* if, for example, I want to emphasize the collaborative feeling of my invitation.  (Unfortunately, when the relationship requires the "together" it is generally hopeless and the person pretty much ignores my invitation -- so I might as well not have tried so hard.)

Comment: @fixer1234: There are tens of thousands of written instances of ***discuss together*** in Google Books, and [nothing in NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=discuss+together&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiscuss%20together%3B%2Cc0) to suggest the collocation has significantly gained or lost currency over the past century. OP here just seems to want us to either endorse or repudiate the usage, which is just an invitation for us to engage in pointless (and inherently ***opinionated***) discussion of "writing style".

Answer (score 0):

Well, if by "trending" you mean that the phrase is currently fashionable and might soon be gone from everyday use, you might want to think again: it's been around for a few centuries.

Consider this book titled *The Works of Alexander Pope, Esq*.; it was published in London in 1824. It includes a biographical sketch in which you will run across the following sentence:

> That Pope and Lord Bolingbroke had for many years been accustomed to **discuss together** moral and metaphysical subjects, and had thereby become acquainted with each other's opinions, is undoubted.

The meaning of the word *discuss* may be a bit confusing in some cases. You state in your question that a discussion, any discussion, has to involve more than one person. In that sense, it is synonymous with the word *debate*.

This is often true; but not always.

One can stand in front of an audience and *discuss* an issue. There's absolutely nothing to prevent one from *discussing* something in a letter to a friend. The original Latin word means "shake," or "take apart," i.e. "take an issue apart in order to see what this or that nuance might yield." In that sense, it is synonymous with "analyze" rather than "debate."

The word *together* may be yet another source of confusion to you - I don't know. It has a number of intriguing connotations. Specifically, in this case it means "all of you (or them, or us) at once." Consider this fragment from Mark Twain's essay:

> [The rules] require that the author shall make the reader feel a deep interest in the personages of his tale and in their fate; and that he shall make the reader love the good people in the tale and hate the bad ones. But the reader of the "Deerslayer" tale dislikes the good people in it, is indifferent to the others, and wishes they would all get drowned **together**.

Thus, "discuss together" could mean (and oftentimes does) "Pick a place and time, gather, and analyze the issue like the intelligent, civilized folks that you are." No more and no less.